# Traffic VHDL simulation issues

Tags: vhdl

I have updated the program, it does finish but now I am trying simulate the project.  I am able to get the clock clear and lights on the pins, but I am not able to get the lights to work and count and states are not even showing.  I believe I have this all set correctly but I could be wrong.  Thank you once again Morten Zilmer for the help with the Error code.

http://tinypic.com/r/24yog0z/8

This is the simulation of the file,
[image: simulation image]

```
entity traffic is
port    (clk: in std_logic;
         clr: in std_logic;
         lights: out std_logic_vector (5 downto 0));
 end traffic;

 architecture traffic of traffic is
 type state_type is (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
 signal state: state_type;
 signal count : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
 constant sec5: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "1111";
 constant sec1: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0011";

 begin
 process(clk, clr)
 begin
if clr = '1' then
        state<= s0;
        count <= x"0";
elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
    case state is
    when s0 =>
        if count <= sec5 then
            state <= s0;
            count <= count +1;
        else
            state <= s1;
            count <= x"0";
            end if;
    when s1 =>
        if count <= sec1 then
            state <= s1;
            count <= count +1;
        else
            state <= s2;
            count <= x"0";
            end if;
    when s2 =>
        if count <= sec1 then
            state <= s2;
            count <= count +1;
        else
            state <= s3;
            count <= x"0";
            end if;
    when s3 =>
        if count <= sec5 then
            state <= s3;
            count <= count +1;
        else
            state <= s4;
            count <= x"0";
            end if;
    when s4 =>
        if count <= sec1 then
            state <= s4;
            count <= count +1;
        else
            state <= s5;
            count <= x"0";
            end if;
    when s5 =>
        if count <= sec1 then
            state <= s5;
            count <= count +1;
        else
            state <= s0;
            count <= x"0";
            end if;
    when others =>
            state <= s0;
end case;
end if;
end process;

c2 : process (state)
begin
case state is
    when s0 => lights <= "100001";
    when s1 => lights <= "100010";
    when s2 => lights <= "100100";
    when s3 => lights <= "001100";
    when s4 => lights <= "010100";
    when s5 => lights <= "100100";
    when others => lights <= "100001";
    end case;
end process;
end traffic;
```

Comment: So let me get this straight, you still have issues and you've accepted Morten's answer? Your question edit covers up that you had a syntax error with `elseif (clk'event and clk = '1') then` on your line 24. Editing away the problem  and question text doesn't leave anything of value for anyone to find reading your question and Morten's answer. It's now unclear. The 'new' question doesn't have a valid answer. –

Comment: I didn't relieaze I should have made a second post.  my original issue was that I couldn't figure out the syntax error.  I just wanted some help with this so I updated my question with the new details instead of creating a new post and thus cluttering the forum.  I am sorry for inconveniencing you David I thought this was how we were supposed to do this.  I will keep this in mind next time I have any kinds of issues.

Comment: Doesn't inconvenience me at all. Does ruin the value of the original question and the still visible accepted answer as part of a knowledge base in lieu of someone else asking again (and else if - elsif shows up a lot, check out the search at the top of the page). If you need an answer to the question as it stands now put this one back to the way Morten answered it, and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `elseif` to `elsif`, for valid VHDL syntax.